# Custom CheckBox image gets cut off

Tags: android, checkbox

[image: CheckBox]

As you can see in the image above. There are three views on this screenshot.
 - The first item is `CheckBox` with text and having state off.
 - The second item is `CheckBox` without text and having state on.
 - The last item is `ImageView` with src pointing to the drawable image.

The CheckBoxes were customized using `android:button`.

[image: small checkbox]

As I tried using smaller images, all of the checkbox is left-aligned.

Comparing these two images tell me that the default size of the `CheckBox` seems fixed to certain size until text attribute is large enough to require extending.

There is nothing special in the file as well. See following.

**custom_cb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/creditcard_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/creditcard"/>

</selector>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbFalse"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:button="@drawable/custom_cb"
              android:text="" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbTrue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:button="@drawable/custom_cb"
              android:focusable="false"
              android:checked="true"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbFalse" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imvTrue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/creditcard"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbTrue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anyway I can use bigger image for CheckBox while keeping the size as `wrap_content`? If I set CheckBox `layout_width` to actual pixel or dp then it display full image but that mean I have to manually check for the size every time it change.

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution to your problem, but I think it should be `android:button="@null"` and use the background attribute instead: `android:background="@drawable/custom_cb"`

Answer (score 62):

Today I had the same problem (my custom image was cutted on the left side).
I fixed it putting:

```
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/my_custom_checkbox_state.xml"
```

Comment: This worked for me, although it does feel like a bug that the CheckBox doesn't respect the size of the android:button drawable when the layout width and height are set to wrap_content..

Comment: Possibly this solution will work differently on different devices

Comment: Thx, a lot. I've tried a lot of solutions with custom button drawable, scaledrawable for button and etc, but your soluton works for me! Buggy android(

Answer (score 16):

Just use

```
android:button="@null"
android:background="@null"
android:drawableLeft="your custom selector"
android:drawablePadding="as you need"
android:text="your text"
```

Thats it.. Its working fine..

Answer (score 4):

You only have to change your drawable from `android:button` to `android:drawableLeft` or `android:drawableRight`. And set the button to null to not show the default checkbox.

My checkbox looks like this:

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/cb_toggle_switch"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:button="@null"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/livescore_btn_check" />
```

Answer (score 2):

CheckBox drawables did not work for me at all, `android:button` and `android:background` gave completely erratic results and nothing could fix it.

So I wrote my own "custom checkbox".

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import com.example.myapp.R;

/**
 * Created by Zhuinden on 2015.12.02..
 */
public class CustomCheckbox
        extends LinearLayout
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    public CustomCheckbox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, -1);
    }

    public CustomCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, -1);
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    public CustomCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public CustomCheckbox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray a = null;
        if(defStyle != -1) {
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CustomCheckbox, defStyle, 0);
        } else {
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.CustomCheckbox);
        }
        defImageRes = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        checkedImageRes = a.getResourceId(1, 0);
        checked = a.getBoolean(2, false);
        typeface = a.getString(3);
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(typeface)) {
            typeface = "Oswald-Book.otf";
        }
        text = a.getString(4);
        inactiveTextcolor = a.getInteger(5, android.R.color.black);
        activeTextcolor = a.getInteger(6, android.R.color.red);
        textsize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(7, 0);
        a.recycle();
        setOnClickListener(this);
        if(!isInEditMode()) {
            LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_checkbox, this, true);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(checked ? checkedImageRes : defImageRes);
            typefaceTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                typefaceTextView.setText(text);
            }
            if(textsize != 0) {
                typefaceTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textsize);
            } else {
                typefaceTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            }
        }
    }

    boolean checked;
    int defImageRes;
    int checkedImageRes;
    String typeface;
    String text;
    int inactiveTextcolor;
    int activeTextcolor;
    int textsize;

    OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;

    @Bind(R.id.custom_checkbox_imageview)
    ImageView imageView;

    @Bind(R.id.custom_checkbox_text)
    TypefaceTextView typefaceTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checked = !checked;
        imageView.setImageResource(checked ? checkedImageRes : defImageRes);
        typefaceTextView.setTextColor(checked ? activeTextcolor : inactiveTextcolor);
        onCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, checked);
    }

    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener) {
        this.onCheckedChangeListener = onCheckedChangeListener;
    }

    public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        void onCheckedChanged(View buttonView, boolean isChecked);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        imageView.setImageResource(checked ? checkedImageRes : defImageRes);
        typefaceTextView.setTextColor(checked ? activeTextcolor : inactiveTextcolor);
    }

    public void setTextColor(int color) {
        typefaceTextView.setTextColor(color);
    }



    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        //begin boilerplate code that allows parent classes to save state
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        //end

        ss.checked = this.checked;
        ss.defImageRes = this.defImageRes;
        ss.checkedImageRes = this.checkedImageRes;
        ss.typeface = this.typeface;
        ss.text = this.text;
        ss.inactiveTextcolor = this.inactiveTextcolor;
        ss.activeTextcolor = this.activeTextcolor;
        ss.textsize = this.textsize;

        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        //begin boilerplate code so parent classes can restore state
        if(!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }

        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        //end

        this.checked = ss.checked;
        this.defImageRes = ss.defImageRes;
        this.checkedImageRes = ss.checkedImageRes;
        this.typeface = ss.typeface;
        this.text = ss.text;
        this.inactiveTextcolor = ss.inactiveTextcolor;
        this.activeTextcolor = ss.activeTextcolor;
        this.textsize = ss.textsize;
    }

    static class SavedState
            extends BaseSavedState {
        boolean checked;
        int defImageRes;
        int checkedImageRes;
        String typeface;
        String text;
        int inactiveTextcolor;
        int activeTextcolor;
        int textsize;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            this.checked = in.readByte() > 0;
            this.defImageRes = in.readInt();
            this.checkedImageRes = in.readInt();
            this.typeface = in.readString();
            this.text = in.readString();
            this.inactiveTextcolor = in.readInt();
            this.activeTextcolor = in.readInt();
            this.textsize = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeByte(this.checked ? (byte) 0x01 : (byte) 0x00);
            out.writeInt(this.defImageRes);
            out.writeInt(this.checkedImageRes);
            out.writeString(this.typeface);
            out.writeString(this.text);
            out.writeInt(this.inactiveTextcolor);
            out.writeInt(this.activeTextcolor);
            out.writeInt(this.textsize);
        }

        //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Using the following `attrs.xml`

```
<resources
    <declare-styleable name="CustomCheckbox">
        <attr name="default_img" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="checked_img" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="checked" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="chx_typeface" format="string"/>
        <attr name="text" format="string"/>
        <attr name="inactive_textcolor" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="active_textcolor" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="textsize" format="dimension"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

With following `view_custom_checkbox.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custom_checkbox_imageview"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
        />

    <com.example.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_checkbox_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</merge>
```

And example:

```
                        <com.example.CustomCheckbox
                            android:id="@+id/program_info_record_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            app:default_img="@drawable/ic_recording_off"
                            app:checked_img="@drawable/ic_recording_on"
                            app:text="@string/record"
                            app:inactive_textcolor="@color/program_info_buttons_inactive"
                            app:active_textcolor="@color/active_color"
                            app:textsize="@dimen/programInfoButtonTextSize"
                            app:chx_typeface="SomeTypeface.otf"/>
```

Modify where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Linearlayout with horizontal orientation instead of RelativeLayout.Also use weight in every layout to force views to use same width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbFalse"
          android:weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:button="@drawable/custom_cb"
          android:text="" />
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbTrue"
          android:weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:button="@drawable/custom_cb"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:checked="true"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbFalse" />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imvTrue"
          android:weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/creditcard"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbTrue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful to someone, setting `gravity` attribute to `center` helped me to avoid image cropping:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_accept_agreement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"/>
```